# Spinner causing BadTokenException on later APIs 13+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I have an app with a Spinner within an onClickListener.  The code works fine with earlier APIs such as API 8, 9, and 10.  It bombs with API 13, 14, 15, 16, and 17.  The error message is:

```
02-01 20:33:03.298: E/AndroidRuntime(812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 20:33:03.298: E/AndroidRuntime(812): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@40cf4bc0 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

What is causing the app to bomb?  The code is as follows:

```
package com.example.spinerr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Button settingsB;
private Spinner mainS, settingsS;
private String[] mainItems = { "Main 1", "Main 2", "Main 3", "Main 4" };
private String[] settingsItems = { "Entry 1", "Entry 2", "Entry 3" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    settingsB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Settings);
    settingsB.setOnClickListener(onSettings);

    mainS = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mainSpinner);
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    ArrayAdapter adapterM = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mainItems);
    mainS.setAdapter(adapterM);
    mainS.setPrompt("Pick item:");
    mainS.setSelection(2);
    mainS.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter4, View v, int i,
                long lng) {
            popUp("in mainS onItemSelected");
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private View.OnClickListener onSettings = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popUp("in onSettings");

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pusettings, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        settingsS = (Spinner) popupView.findViewById(R.id.settingsSpinner);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> tAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
        getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                settingsItems);

        settingsS.setAdapter(tAdapter);
        settingsS.setPrompt("Pick an entry:");
        settingsS.setSelection(0);
        settingsS.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 
                              AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter1,
            View v, int i, long lng) {
               popUp("In settings onItemSelected.");
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
            }
        });
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(settingsB, 1, 1);
    }
};

private void popUp(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

activity_main.XML is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/Lime"
>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="80dp"
        android:height="36dp"
    /> 
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mainSpinner"
        android:prompt="@string/pick"
        android:text="@string/press"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  />  
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

pusettings.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Gold"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/Citrus"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/settings" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/settingsSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Added--full stack trace:

```
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41087988 is not valid; is your activity running?
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:515)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:279)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:988)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:897)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:595)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:739)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:435)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-02 00:27:28.459: E/AndroidRuntime(624):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post a full stack trace of the error

Answer (score 0):

The spinner onItemSelected listener is getting fired off when the layout first renders (and of course when you change the selection), which may be too soon in the activity lifecycle for a toast message to have a good context. Wrap your toast with a try-catch and see if that catches the exception, or if the exception is being thrown elsewhere.

Comment: No, toast isn't the problem.  I commented out the toast statement.  Same problem.

Comment: full trace posted.  Cannot capture error with try-catch.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The BadTokenException went away with later API versions.  No longer having the problem.